# check function not waiting for response

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I am trying to create a telegram bot and this function doesn't work as intended function checks if the user is new if so then it ask for name and age and it should wait until the user enters the name and then proceed but it doesn't

```
async function check(chat_id) {
  const firstText =
    "Hi there! Before you start using the bot, you need to enter the following details: name, age";
  const res = await Subscription.findOne({ chatId: chat_id });

  if (!res) {
    let name;
    let age;

    await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, firstText);
    await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Name?");

    await bot.once("message", async (message) => {
      name = message.text.trim().toLowerCase();
    });

    await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Age?");
    bot.once("message", async (message) => {
      age = message.text.trim().toLowerCase();
    });

    try {
      // Create a new subscription document in the database
      await Subscription.create({
        chatId: chat_id,
        name: name,
        age: age,
      });

      // Now you can use the captured name and age for further processing
      await bot.sendMessage(
        chat_id,
        "Thanks for providing your details. You are now registered!"
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error inserting data:", error.message);
      await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Error occurred. Please try again later.");
    }
  } else return;
}
```

Comment: You said don't wait then are surprised it does not? `async function check(chat_id) {`  note:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function "Async functions always return a promise."

Comment: `name = message.text.trim().toLowerCase()` inside an asynchronous callback is definitely code smell.  And, then you try to use `name` later in the same function expecting it to be valid.  This is definitely wrong.  You would benefit from learning more about asynchronous programming and how the event loop works in Javascript and how event handlers are non-blocking.  And, `await` only does something useful when you await a promise so `await bot.once(...)` doesn't `await` anything.

Comment: can you guys help me , what should i change in my code ??

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `once` event is triggered whenever user enters something.
First time its name and then age. You need to try creating subscription once both data is received.

I hope below code works for you -

```
async function check(chat_id) {
    const firstText =
      "Hi there! Before you start using the bot, you need to enter the following details: name, age";
    const res = await Subscription.findOne({ chatId: chat_id });
  
    if (!res) {
      let name;
      let age;
  
      await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, firstText);
      await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Name?");
    
      let msgCounter = 0;
      bot.once("message", async (message) => {
        if (msgCounter === 0) {
            name = message.text.trim().toLowerCase();
        } else if (msgCounter === 1) {
            age = message.text.trim().toLowerCase();
        } else {
            // Handle Unexpected case
        }
        msgCounter++;
        if (msgCounter === 1) {
            await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Age?");
        } else {
            // Both received
            await doSomething(chat_id, name, age);
        }

      });
    } else return;
  }


async function doSomething(chat_id, name, age) {
    try {
        // Create a new subscription document in the database
        await Subscription.create({
          chatId: chat_id,
          name: name,
          age: age,
        });
  
        // Now you can use the captured name and age for further processing
        await bot.sendMessage(
          chat_id,
          "Thanks for providing your details. You are now registered!"
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error inserting data:", error.message);
        await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Error occurred. Please try again later.");
      }
}
```